# Who are the Ishmaelites whom God regrets creating (Sukkah 52b:)?

Tags: yishmael

(to help Kenny with his [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/126803/should-this-be-used-as-an-excuse-for-islamaphobia)).

> "אָמַר רַב חָנָא בַּר אַחָא, אָמְרִי בֵּי רַב:
> ארבעה מתחרט עליהן הקדוש ברוך הוא שבראם ואלו הם:
> גלות, כשדים, וישמעאלים ויצר הרע
> There are four that the Holy One, Blessed is He, regrets
> having created. And these are they: The exile, the Chaldeans, the
> Ishmaelites, and the evil inclination. [Sukkah 52b:](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sukkah.52b.7?lang=bi&with=all&l)?

Who are the Ishmaelites whom God regrets creating?

Answer (score 2):

We all know that the Islamic world was yet to exist in the times of the Talmud, so we should not connect the Talmudic Ishmaelites to nowadays Arabs in any way (even though some interpreters try).

[Rashi interprets the verse](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.52b.8?lang=bi&p2=Job.12.6&lang2=bi&w2=Rashi&lang3=en&p4=Genesis.16.12&lang4=bi&aliyot4=0), quoted in the Gemmora as following:

> "I know that at times, tents will prosper, namely those of the **Kedarites** who dwell in tents in the deserts, and who are robbers, as it is stated (Gen. 16:12): “a free man among men; his hand shall be against every man.”"

So Rashi connects specifically the [Qedarite nation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qedarites) with the general term "Ishmael". To remind you that Kedar is Ishmael's son ([Gen.25.13](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.25.13?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&qh=%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%A8)).

As is seen from Isaiah and Jeremiah, the Israelites suffered frequently from the Qedarites to the point that the Babylonian Gemmorah reflects on that.